# Join two tables without nulls reflecting in the results

Tags: sql, oracle

Below are the 2 tables that I try to join,

table 1:

```
+--------+--------+---------+------+-----+--------+
| seq_id | req_id | ctrl_id | CODE | c2  | status |
+--------+--------+---------+------+-----+--------+
|      1 |      3 | C001    | ABC  |   0 | PASS   |
|      2 |      3 | C001    | EFG  |   0 | PASS   |
|      3 |      3 | C001    | HIJ  |   0 | PASS   |
+--------+--------+---------+------+-----+--------+
```

table 2:

```
+--------+--------+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
| seq_id | Req_id | ctrl_id | source |  c1   |     c2      |
+--------+--------+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
|      1 |      5 | C001    | S1     |   ABC | 32331235662 |
|      2 |      5 | C001    | S1     |   EFG |  8966492700 |
|      3 |      5 | C001    | S1     |   HIJ | 12656678121 |
|      4 |      5 | C001    | S2     |   ABC | 32331235662 |
|      5 |      5 | C001    | S2     |   EFG |  8966492700 |
|      6 |      5 | C001    | S2     |   HIJ | 12656678121 |
+--------+--------+---------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

I'm using the below query to join these tables,

```
select a.seq_id, a.req_id, a.ctrl_id, a.CODE,
       (case when b.source = 'S1' then  b.c2 end) as source1 ,   
       (case when b.source = 'S2' then  b.c2 end) as source2, a.c2, a.status
from table1 a  
  join  table2 b on  a.ctrl_id=b.ctrl_id  and a.code=b.c1
order by a.seq_id
```

the result that i get is,

```
seq_id  Req_id  ctrl_id CODE    SOURCE1          SOURCE2        c2  status
1          5    C001    ABC      NULL             32331235662   0   PASS
1          5    C001    ABC      32331235662      NULL          0   PASS
2          5    C001    EFG      NULL             8966492700    0   PASS
2          5    C001    EFG      8966492700       NULL          0   PASS
3          5    C001    HIJ      NULL             12656678121   0   PASS
3          5    C001    HIJ      12656678121      NULL          0   PASS
```

I am trying to get the below as result, without the null values,

```
seq_id  Req_id  ctrl_id CODE    SOURCE1          SOURCE2        c2  status
1          5    C001    ABC      32331235662      32331235662   0   PASS
2          5    C001    EFG      8966492700       8966492700    0   PASS
3          5    C001    HIJ      12656678121      12656678121   0   PASS
```

Please assist.

Comment: I don't know your data, but I'd consider a GROUP BY, or perhaps a self join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use grouping for this task

Like this

```
select a.seq_id, a.req_id, a.ctrl_id, a.CODE,
       max(case when b.source = 'S1' then  b.c2 end) as source1 ,   
       max(case when b.source = 'S2' then  b.c2 end) as source2, a.c2, a.status
from table1 a  
  join  table2 b on  a.ctrl_id=b.ctrl_id  and a.code=b.c1
group by a.seq_id, a.req_id, a.ctrl_id, a.CODE,a.c2, a.status
order by a.seq_id
```

Comment: This is perfect Viktor. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use joins to get the two separate fields you are after and just amend them onto your original dataset.

In this case the joins are SELF JOINS to the same table to get the specified values.

```
    select a.seq_id, b.req_id, a.ctrl_id, a.CODE,
           s1.c2 AS [Source1] ,
           s2.c2 AS [Source2],
           a.c2,
           a.status
    from table1 a  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b 
            ON a.seq_id = b.seq_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 s1
            ON s1.req_id = b.req_id AND s1.c1 = b.c1 AND s1.[source] = 'S1'
      LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 s2
            ON s2.req_id = b.req_id AND s2.c1 = b.c1 AND s2.[source] = 'S2'
    order by a.seq_id
```

Comment: arahman - I am missing something in your query, i get -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @Chand I have amended the query so it should work for you. I think because you are doing Oracle and not MSSQL some of my syntax was slightly different.